# Invert Core Animation Direction

Tags: cabasicanimation

How can i change the vertical Direction of an Animation?

Currently i have this:

```
-(void) flipAway{
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
    self.view.layer.zPosition = 100;

    CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 1, 0, 0);
    transform.m34 = 1.0/800.0;
    [animation setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:transform]];
    [animation setDuration:5];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];
    [animation setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
    [animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
    [animation setDelegate:self];

    [self.view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"test"];
}
```

And this works, BUT the rotation is a flip from top to bottom, how can i invert this to be from bottom to top?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're asking for.

```
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(- M_PI, 1, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The target was to invert Animation Direction : instead from bottom to top , i wanted to have it from top to bottom, i finally achieved this by adding an anchor Point for the animation:

```
CGRect frame = self.view.layer.frame;
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(frame), frame.size.height);
    self.view.layer.position = center;
    self.view.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1);
```

I don't know why, but once you add this lines, the animation inverts..